# What is the name for a pentagonal base extruded to a triangle?

Tags: geometry

I am a chemist and am seeking to name the following shape which ties to an arrangement of atoms.

Unfortunately I'm not able to post the actual structure owing to IP considerations, nor am I competent in 3d modelling software, so I hope that my verbal description suffices.

The shape could be described as:

An extrusion from a pentagonal base to a smaller, triangular cap.

and/or

A not-prism (in the sense that it looks like a prism but is not in fact such) with a pentagonal base and a triangular cap, which is smaller than the pentagon.

Comment: What about the faces and edges? If you have 3 vertices on the one side and 5 on the other, then how do they connected to each other?

Comment: Not every shape has a name. I suspect the shape you have in mind doesn't have one.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski I think I'd find that a bit hard to relay via text other than to say that the nearest vertices of each 'base' join at the nearest vertex on the other base.

The base of the triangle is positioned such that viewed from above, the vertices point towards the sides of the pentagon.

Comment: Is it a [prismatoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prismatoid)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the closest thing to the description of the shape
is a [prismatoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prismatoid):
"In geometry, a prismatoid is a polyhedron where all vertices lie in two parallel planes."

[image]